# How to get an object of Devcon output using PowerShell (winpe)?

Tags: arrays, powershell, winpe, devcon

I would like to select an object from Devcon.exe output.

```
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_2822&SUBSYS_1790103C&REV_04\3&11583659&0&FA
    Name: Intel(R) Chipset SATA/PCIe RST Premium Controller
Driver node #0:
    Inf file is C:\Windows\INF\iastorav.inf
    Inf section is iaStorAVC_inst
    Driver description is Intel Chipset SATA RAID Controller
    Manufacturer name is Intel Corporation
    Provider name is Intel Corporation
    Driver date is 2/7/2018
    Driver version is 15.44.0.1010
    Driver node rank is 16711683
    Driver node flags are 00102044
        Inf is digitally signed
Driver node #1:
    Inf file is C:\Windows\INF\oem9.inf
    Inf section is iaStorAC_inst_8
    Driver description is Intel(R) Chipset SATA/PCIe RST Premium Controller
    Manufacturer name is Intel Corporation
    Provider name is Intel Corporation
    Driver date is 5/9/2019
    Driver version is 17.5.0.1017
    Driver node rank is 8388611
    Driver node flags are 00003044
        Inf is digitally signed
```

I want to get the `Driver version` by mapping the `Driver description` .
I tried this way, but I can not get the Driver version.

```
 $hardwareid = "PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_2822&SUBSYS_1790103C&REV_04"
 $Description = "Intel(R) Chipset SATA/PCIe RST Premium Controller"
 $DrNode = & .\devcon.exe /drivernodes "$hardwareid"             
 $Ver = $DrNode | Where-Object {$_ -like "*$Description*"} | Select-Object Driver version
```

Anyone can give idea please. Really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble is devcon outputs text.  How about something like this using WMI?

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver | 
  where description -match 'apple solid state drive device' |
  select driverversion

driverversion
-------------
6.0.6400.0
```

Ok, this worked for me in winpe.  I got it here:  https://superuser.com/questions/1438704/how-to-find-driver-version-for-all-devices-through-wmi/1438715#1438715  It gets the version of the driver from the file info.

```
get-wmiobject Win32_SystemDriver | select DisplayName,@{n="version";
  e={(get-item $_.pathname).VersionInfo.FileVersion}} | 
  where displayname -match 'apple solid state drive'

DisplayName                    version
-----------                    -------
Apple Solid State Drive Device 6.0.6400.0
```

Comment: Thank you, but I will execute it under winpe, so  Win32_PnPSignedDriver is not available :(